# How to update Gnome environment after gpasswd

Tags: gnome

when adding some group users running Gnome

```
gpasswd -a user group
```

I am unable to see the changes running

```
id
```

Is there a way to update the environment without the need
to restart Gnome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the terminal to reflect the updated group membership, it should be sufficient to use `su` to "switch" to the same user e.g.

```
$ id -Gn
steeldriver adm dialout sudo staff sambashare
$ 
$ sudo gpasswd --add steeldriver lpadmin
Adding user steeldriver to group lpadmin
$ 
$ id -Gn
steeldriver adm dialout sudo staff sambashare
```

(still shows the old groups), but then

```
$ su - steeldriver
Password: 
$ id -Gn
steeldriver adm dialout sudo staff lpadmin sambashare
```

If you need the changes to be reflected throughout the desktop environment then yes, you will need to log out and in to a new session.